# Cannot access com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine

Tags: java, hawtio

I am trying to deploy the hawtio-default-offline-1.3.1.war (into JBoss EAP 6.2) and I see this message in the logs:

10:16:07,988 WARN  [io.hawt.jvm.local.JVMList] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Local JVM discovery disabled as this JVM cannot access com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine due to: com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine

So I don't have a local tab when I start up hawtio. Is this OK? This is my local Windows laptop and I am deploying the hawtio WAR alongside my app WAR and I am launching it using the JBoss bat file. I do a jps and I can see the JBoss server running.
Appreciate any pointers, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is okay, the WARNING is only about the connect plugin, not being able to use the local discovery. You can always use remote discovery, also to connect to local.

But if you only need that hawtio application deployed in your EAP to manage and monitor whats running in the same JVM then this is no problem.

There is also a FAQ at hawtio about related to this.
http://hawt.io/faq/